# Hibernate insert foreign key

Tags: hibernate, insert, hql

I'm using hibernate to insert some rows but I don't know if I'm doing well...

My enity has a foreign key and i know its id, I can't understand if I need the referenced object or just the id.
I how there is a way to do this because it is not useful getting the referenced object just for insert.

I want to do this:

```
en=new MyEntity();
en.setForeignVal("1");
```

Seems i have to do this:

```
en=new MyEntity();
refObj=getSession().get(RefObject.class, "1"); //unuseful
en.setForeignVal(refObj);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate provides a special method for this use case - `load()`. It returns a proxy with the given id without hitting the database:

```
en.setForeignVal(getSession().load(RefObject.class, "1"));
```

Comment: Thank you... the verb "load" is exactly what i did not want :-)

Comment: Just a note that load() will return an initialized entity in cases when a) you have lazy="false" for the whole class in your mapping b) you use a bytecode enhancement mechanism instead of proxies.